# CSS Child selectors no IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Hoje eu precisei fazer um fix para IE8 no qual eu utilizava o seguinte seletor para alinhar 3 caixas horizontalmente.

```
#page-content .section-servicos .box-servico:nth-child(3n+2){ margin-right:0px; }
```

no IE8 este código não funciona, então resolvi fazer com JQuery pois sabia que assim iria funcionar.

Foi ai então que surgiu a minha dúvida.

**Existe outra maneira de se reproduzir este mesmo efeito de seletor apenas com CSS e que funcione no IE8?**

Segue abaixo o fix em JQuery que utilizei para solucionar o problema (só pro caso de alguém precisar).

```
$('.box-servico:nth-child(3n+2)').css('margin-right', '0px');
```

.

**EDIT**: Encontrei um artigo muito bom explicando a funcionalidade dos seletores CSS. **[LINK AQUI](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/)**

Comment: respondi exatamente sua pergunta, sem uso de Javascript. Se acreditar que está melhor, você ainda pode trocar e por como resposta certa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, existe um jeito de emular apenas com CSS e sem javascript, pontos que são requisitos da pergunta, nth-child apenas com CSS. Dá um pouco mais de trabalho, mas é viável.

### Sintaxe de [Adjacent sibling selectors, Documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

> former_element + target_element { style properties }

### Sintaxe de [:first-child, Documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child):

> element:first-child { style properties }

### Equivalente nth-child com fist-child e sibling

```
/* Primeiro filho */
li:nth-child(1) {}
li:first-child {}

/* Segundo filho */
li:nth-child(2) {}
li:first-child + li {}

/* Terceiro filho filho */
li:nth-child(3) {}
li:first-child + li + li {}
```

### Como fazer nth-child(odd), nth-child(3n+2) e outros?

Neste caso, é um pouco mais trabalhoso. Para funcionar com IE8 e até IE7 você vai precisar por manualmente todos os equivalentes separados por virgula até um limite aonde achar interessante nth-child calcularia até o infinito, porém no seu CSS teria que por um número até aonde acha pertinente

```
li:nth-child(2n) {}
/* Equivalente até o oitavo valor */
li:first-child + li,
li:first-child + li + li +li,
li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li,
li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li + li + li {
}
```

### Alternativas

Outras soluções necessariamente vão envolver código javascript ou por marcação adicional no seu HTML. A não ser que seja realmente necessário e nada simples de resolver, não é interessante adicionar ainda mais javascript na sua página, em especial se ela for complexa.

IE8 e em especial IE7 podem demorar muito, mas muito mais tempo para processar a página ao usar polyfills a um ponto em que é inaceitável.

Uma página que renderizada em 200ms no Chrome, ao usar polyfills para nth-child chegava tranquilo a 7 segundos. Na época resolvi apenas adicionando mais classes no HTML

Comment: Que sacada em amigo, todos usando js e você simplesmente CSS, genial ;]

Comment: Um salve, essa pra mim é realmente nova

Answer (score 3):

Como podemos ver [neste artigo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) da Microsoft o [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8) não é completamente compatível com algumas propriedades do [css3](/questions/tagged/css3):

> O Windows Internet Explorer 8 é totalmente compatível com a
>   especificação CSS, Nível 2 Revisão 1 (CSS 2.1), e oferece suporte a
>   alguns recursos de CSS Nível 3 (CSS 3).

Observando o trecho que comenta sobre as [pseudo-classes](/questions/tagged/pseudo-classes) [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Pseudoclasses), podemos perceber que nenhuma versão do [ie](/questions/tagged/ie) igual ou inferior ao [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8) é compatível com as [pseudo-classes](/questions/tagged/pseudo-classes):
`:root`, `:nth-child()`, `:nth-last-child()`, `:nth-of-type()`,
`:nth-last-of-type()`, `:last-child`, `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`,
`:only-child`, `:only-of-type`, `:empty`, `:target`, `:not(X)`, `:enabled`,
`:disabled`, `:checked`, `:indeterminate`, `:default`, `:valid`, `:invalid`,
`:in-range`, `:out-of-range`, `:required`, `:optional`, `:read-only` e `:read-write`

Desta forma usar [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) ou algum de seus [principais frameworks](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3637/principais-frameworks-de-javascript.aspx) se torna a melhor solução para se tratar a situação sem que seja necessário fazer modificações no seu [html](/questions/tagged/html) ou [css](/questions/tagged/css).

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, é mais ou menos isso que eu achava que tava rolando com essa _benção_ de navegador, haha... Valeu. =)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar classes nos elementos que irão usar esse estilo:

```css
#page-content .section-servicos .box-servico.ultima{ margin-right:0px; }
```

Comment: Assim ja ia fugir do esquema de seletor, mas seria sim uma solução.

Comment: Usar javascript não é ruim, mas como todo mundo usa é a sugestão que todos deram. Por outro lado, como já vi vários sites feitos para IE8 que usam classes para isso, tentei dar uma sugestão diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode utilizar o [IE9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

Só incluir:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Como eu só precisava deste fix não rola colocar um plugin só pra isso, ia 'pesar' o site, mas acredito que também seria uma otima solução, caso eu tivesse adotado seu uso desde o inicio do projeto. hehe, valeeu =)

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma solução "leve" mas existe um projeto que cria um Polyfill para IE8 ter suporte mais completo a CSS3.

**[Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)**

Por nativo o IE8 não suporta tanto no seu "querySelector" quanto no próprio CSS a maioria dos pseudo-seletores de CSS3, também falha quando se usa pseudo-seletores de ancora em um nível mais baixo, por exemplo:

```
a:hover div // Nunca será achado no IE8 mesmo que seu mouse esteja em cima da ancora que contenha uma div
```

Comment: É como vc disse **não é uma solução leve** e como eu não precisaria de praticamente mais nada desse plugin(que é otimo) para esse fix, ficaria inviavel um plugin. Mas valeu. :) ps: inviavel mesmo é usarem IE8, mas já que usam, vamos empurrando isso pra frente...